# Protractor sendKeys sometimes does not send anything to textbox

Tags: protractor

I have few test in which every test login to application using the below code, but I am facing issue where for few of the test  sendKey(domainID) will enter the correct value but for few of the test it will just enter blank, I can see that while test is running.

```
exports.login = function(userName, password, domainID) { 
loginPage.domainId.click().then(function(){
    loginPage.domainId.clear().sendKeys(domainID);
});
loginPage.username.click().then(function(){
    loginPage.username.clear().sendKeys(userName);
});
loginPage.password.click().then(function(){
    loginPage.password.clear().sendKeys(password);
});    
};
```

I am calling above same function with same input parameters from all of my Test

```
LoginMod.login('Username1', 'Password1', 'DomainID1');
```

Also if I run my test individually all will login and sendKey will enter proper DomainID but if I run entire test Suite SendKey Does not send DoaminID for few of the test and hence my test will fail.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do you get any errormessages on this?

Comment: No I do not get any error it's just doe not enter any text I can see that while running my test.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `click()` to give focus on element before `sendKeys()`.
This always worked for me.

Comment: I am using `click()` in `loginPage.domainId.click().then(function(){` line